# DB2 Tablespace Size mismatch

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am trying to get the tablespace size for a DB2 EEE setup. 
When I do following command:

```
db2 => list tablespaces 
 Tablespace ID                        = 1
 Name                                 = TEMPSPACE1
 Type                                 = System managed space
 Contents                             = System Temporary data
 State                                = 0x0000
   Detailed explanation:
    Normal
 Total pages                          = 1
 Useable pages                        = 1
 Used pages                           = 1
 Free pages                           = Not applicable
 High water mark (pages)              = Not applicable
 Page size (bytes)                    = 4096
 Extent size (pages)                  = 32
 Prefetch size (pages)                = 32
 Number of containers                 = 1
```

Above command works fine for single instance DB while in case of DB2EEE, we need to get the tablespace size from each node and add it up or other way is to use the bellow query:

```
db2 -c "select TABLESPACE_NAME,usable_pages as TBSPC_Pages from table (snapshot_tbs_cfg ('DB2EEE',-2))

TABLESPACE           2                    TABLESPACE_SIZE
----------------------------------------- --------------------
TEMPSPACE1            0                    0
```

Above query is returning number of pages for the same tablespace as '0' while previous command returned it as '1'.

Any idea which one of the above is correct and why?
Or is there any other way to find the size of tablespace in DB2 (Single noe and EEE instances both)

Comment: The issue is observed with DB2 9.5 version

Answer (score 0):

Even though this table function has been deprecated (it was deprecated in DB2 9.1), this looks like a bug in `SNAPSHOT_TBS_CFG`, which has been corrected in more current versions (I don't see this bug in 9.7.3).  It's been replaced with the much more useful `SNAPTBSP_PART` administrative view.

Please note that with DPF (née EEE), using this table function with the global argument for the database partition number (`-2`)  is not particularly useful as it does include the database partition number in its output - so for tablespaces spanning multiple database partitions you will get multiple rows returned with no way to tell which row came from which database partition.

Comment: For SNAPTBSP_PART I am getting the `TBSP_TOTAL_PAGES` as Zero. Do you think that's the correct one while size `list tablespaces` is the wrong one?
I am using DB2 version 9.5

Comment: No, as I said it's a bug in `SNAPSHOT_TBS_CFG` that has likely been fixed in a newer Fixpack release of 9.5; `list tablespaces` is correct.